# Howto rewrite MySQL NOT IN query using a join?

Tags: mysql

i use a sql query like this to get some results i need:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    pictures p
WHERE
    p.id NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT
                picture_id
            FROM
                guesses g
            WHERE 
                g.user_id = XXX 
        )
    AND
        p.user_id != XXX
;
```

Relation is as follows: A user has many pictures and a picture belongs to one user. A user has many guesses and a guess belongs to one picture. The tricky part is that a user is only allowed one guess for the same picture.

XXX = $user_id

I guess that there is a way to rewrite this sub-select using a left join but i can't get it working.

Can anyone help?

Anja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a `NOT IN` condition you should use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. This is the direct translation to left outer join of your query:

```
SELECT
    distinct p.*
FROM
    pictures p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   guesses g      ON g.picture_id = p.id and g.user_id = XXX
WHERE
   p.user_id != XXX
   and g.user_id is null
;
```

Comment: Hey danihp, thanks for your answer. However your query is not working. i get this error message:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN guesses g ON g.picture_id = p.id WHERE p.user_id != ' at line 7

Comment: sorry! copy-paste issue. Try now, please.

Comment: With my query i get 187 results and when i try your's on the same database i only get 154 ... so what could be the problem?

Comment: two possibilities, because do you have duplicate rows on pictures table (I don't think) or because I forgot include subquery condition in on clause. Please, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here we go. I guess that is the correct answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.*
FROM
    pictures p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    guesses g      
ON 
    g.picture_id = p.id and g.user_id = 1
WHERE
    g.user_id is null
    and p.user_id != 1
;
```